# Adobe-Brackets Angularjs Code Completion

Tags: editor, angular-ui, adobe-brackets, tern

I am using adobe-brackets sprint39 to build the front end of websites.
I am a heavy user of Angularjs.
https://angularjs.org/

Is it possible to activate angularjs code completion on the adobe-brackets ide?
Tern has been integrated with adobe-brackets and it has an angular plugin.
http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#plugin_angular
The angular-ui team have written an angularjs plugin for brackets.
https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-brackets

I have installed it as an extension, however, am not still able to achieve angularjs code completion.

Has anyone managed to have angularjs code completion on adobe-brackets? If so, would you be kind enough to show me how to do so? Does the adobe-brackets angularjs code completion work on the html markup or does it only work when one is coding the javascript?
Any help would be appreciated. I have searched on the internet and have not found any clear instructions on how to achieve angularjs code-completion on adobe-brackets. Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [a plugin](https://github.com/sirajc/Brackets-AngularJS-CodeHints/)!
It does suggest/autocomplete html attributes for *many* Angular directives and attributes.
I just played for 15 Minutes with it. ng-form seems to be missing.
To say it explicitly:
If you want to activate code completion for angularJs in html files install it via the common procedure.
The search term is "angular hints" in the extension management dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy. Put the cursor in the place you want to code-completion and press **ctrl+e**. If is an angular attribute (directive, controller or service) and you have the angularUI extension, you will be able to edit the 'backend code'. In a standard html tag, you will be able to edit the css for this tag.

enjoy with brackets!

PS: Sorry about my english. It is my firt post.

Comment: Thanks, I got the message. Angularjs front end code hinting is not yet support in brackets...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only working when coding the javascript, it does not work with angular html attributes, I was googling for a while and didn`t find any traces of plugins/extensions to add this feature.

Without this functionality Bracket is not useful for developing angular apps IMO, I'll have to wait until it will be implemented